# EE3 How to show random template variables

Tags: variable, random

I created some template variables which is https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/templates/globals/template_variable.html, how can I show one of them randomly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in way to do this. But you could [write a simple add-on](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/development/plugins.html) which selects a random variable from the database and returns it.